# Creating Custom Widget in Visual Studio in Orchard 1.7

Tags: orchardcms

I am trying to build a very simple widget with two input fields Name and Email address. Right now I am following http://www.deepcode.co.uk/search?q=how+to+build+a+widget+without+a+model+in+Orchard.

### Migration.cs

```
public int UpdateFrom22()
{
    ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("QuickLinkWidget", builder => builder
    .WithPart("QuickLinkWidgetPart")
    .WithPart("CommonPart")
    .WithPart("WidgetPart")
    .WithSetting("Stereotype", "Widget"));

    return 23;
}
```

### ContentPartRecord (Models/QuickLinkWidgetRecord.cs)

```
public class QuickLinkWidgetRecord : ContentPartRecord

{
    //We shall not define any property for this class.
    //We shall not create any HANDLER for this widget because we do not need to store any data to our database.
}
```

### ContentPart: (Models/QuickLinkWidgetPart.cs)

```
public class QuickLinkWidgetPart : ContentPart<QuickLinkWidgetRecord>
{
    //Again we shall not definte any Record property here......
    //We shall not create any HANDLER for this widget because we do not need to store any data to our database.
}
```

### Handler

Did not define any as I don't have deal with any repository.

### Driver: ((Models/QuickLinkWidgetDriver.cs))

```
public class QuickLinkWidgetDriver : ContentPartDriver<QuickLinkWidgetPart>

{
    override DriverResult Display(QuickLinkWidgetPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
    //We do not have any property defined in Model class.
    //So we don't have to assign any Default values to anything!
    //We shall just return a SHAPE of the widget
    }
}
```

### Placement.info:

```
<Place Widgets_QuickLinkWidget="AsideFirst:1" />
```

### And finally the View: Views/Widgets/QuickLinkWidget.cshtml

```
@using Emfluence.Intrust.Models;

@model Contact

<h2>Our Side link widget</h2>
```

Nothing extra I added in my View

Please help me understanding what I am doing wrong. Why I am not able to see the widget rendered at all? I am stuck with it for the last 3 days!, just want to see it rendering first!

Thanks in advance fro your help

Comment: Your driver doesn't have anything in it? And your placement needs to say to show your part, not the widget. Then create the widget from the dashboard.

Comment: Can you add any example, I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and i got it working by changing some setting on my placement.info file...in your case try this

```
<Place Widgets_QuickLinkWidget="Content" />
```

Comment: Change what setting? Can you [edit] to explain further?